# eclipse product access database file causes error

Tags: database, eclipse, file, rcp

I am building an RCP application. I have only one plugin project and I'm trying to export as product.
I use an sqlite database file .
While I am testying both my application and my product from Run of eclipse having NO PROBLEM at all,
when I export the product , database access fails. This is how I open the database connection

`dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:"+FileLocator.resolve(Platform.getBundle("BundleID").getEntry("dbFile")).getPath());`

My dbFile is in my projects root file, and after the export , it is found in the BundleID.jar in the plugins folder, and so the application cannot open it as the path calculated is sth like.... "/plugins/BundleId.jar!/dbFile"

The "!" before / is in the String!!!

Is there Something I could do in order to overcome this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `FileLocator.toFileURL()` on the `URL` returned by `FileLocator.resolve()` to get a more normal URL.

Note: this will expand your jar in to a temporary cache so that a normal file URL can be returned. This cache is not guaranteed to be persistent so if you want database changes to persist you need to put the database somewhere else.

One possibility is to copy the database to the workspace .metadata in the plugin state data (see `Platform.getStateLocation(bundle)`.

Comment: Do you think that putting my File in the exported project root directory and supplying the path through command line arguments would be a good approach?

Comment: Added suggested location to answer. Note the plugin install location may be read only in some Eclipse installs.

Comment: I'm preety disappointed and Very confused... I still have problem with my product... As long as I run the app inside eclipse, either the .application either my .product everything works fine.. When I export the product I cannot make it work even after trying to pass the exact path to the database through command line arguments!!! Any good explanation for this????

Comment: Did you put the db in the state location in the .metadata? I use a Derby db this way (db is created from scratch in the location).

Comment: I just copied my database there. I shall try create the datavbase in my application and test again.